# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header... Is my Beego server misconfigured?

Tags: go, cors, beego

I am using Beego/Golang as my backend and having an issue with `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` when trying to fetch a URL from my domain. I searched on Google and put this in `func main()` but it still does not work, I still have the same error.

```
// (my own code) FilterUser is used to redirect users to login 
// when they try to access some pages without logging in
beego.InsertFilter("/*", beego.BeforeExec, FilterUser)

// This is what I found on Google
beego.InsertFilter("*", beego.BeforeRouter, cors.Allow(&cors.Options{
        AllowAllOrigins: true,
        AllowMethods: []string{"GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"},
        AllowHeaders: []string{"Origin"},
        ExposeHeaders: []string{"Content-Length"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
    }))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting both `AllowCredentials` and `AllowAllOrigins`. A casual examination of [the source code of Beego's `cors` package](https://gitee.com/mirrors/beego/blob/v1.10.1/plugins/cors/cors.go) indicates that, as a result, responses to preflight requests contain the following combination of headers:

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

However, the [Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol) (which defines how CORS works) instructs browsers to reject this combination—because honouring it would be *very* insecure. See [this relevant passage of the MDN Web Docs about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards):

> When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "`*`" wildcard.

One way to fix the issue would be to allow, not all origins, but only the origin of your frontend; I used `https://example.com` as a placeholder below:

```golang
beego.InsertFilter("*", beego.BeforeRouter, cors.Allow(&cors.Options{
    AllowOrigins: []string{"https://example.com"}, // <---
    // -snip-
    AllowCredentials: true,
}))
```

Comment: Do you mean changing `AllowAllOrigins: true` to `AllowOrigins: []string{"https://mywebsite.io/*"}`?

Comment: @VII Yes, that's what I mean.